# Minecraft server not working

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-buster, server, minecraft

I want to run a Minecraft server from a Raspberry Pi 2. I already tried the 1.8.9 and the 1.15.2 versions. Both of them started, as expected. On my computer I tried to connect, but after a while, it said, that the connection has timed out. I use a Wi-Fi dongle on the Pi. I am running the newest version of raspbian buster. Does the Pi have a bit to little RAM? Thank's for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you able to connect and play before it times out or does it never connect at all?

Comment: It doesn't connect at all.

Comment: Could you expand the question to include the output of running the minecraft jar? If you are getting the usually `generating world` gubbins its probably running ok. Are you able to ping your Pi from your PC?

Comment: The server starts as it is supposed to. I was able to ping the Pi from the PC. The server even shows the player connecting. But then it times out. I have the Pi right next to the router.

Comment: You could try moving the Pi two or three feet away from the router.  I've had issues with access points and devices too close to them (wild stab in the dark TBH)

Comment: I tried it, but still doesn't work.

Comment: I got a new raspberry pi 4, and copied the files from the pi 2, and it works. But I would still like to know, what is wrong.

Comment: I have a Minecraft Server on my Raspberry Pi 4, and it runs just fine. You never know if the issue was related to ram or the older versions of the Raspberry Pi don't handle Minecraft servers very well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that you may be running out of ram. You may want to set the preset ram to a slightly higher number, allowing the server to utilize the ram more efficiently. I have a video dedicated on how to set up a Minecraft Server (only on the Pi 4): https://youtu.be/SBX-90NcAJo